# need to distinguish columns of a table by other columns of another table php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my query:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM
(
    SELECT postId, postContent, postDate FROM posts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT commentId, commentContent, commentDate FROM comments
) q
ORDER BY postDate DESC
```

I get the results of the query by the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function in a `while` loop.

When i `print_r()` the result i get as keys the columns in the first `SELECT`.

How do i get the comments too as keys?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely what you had in mind when you wrote that union query, nor do I know exactly what you want to do with the result set.  But one option which might work here would be to add a computed column to the union query, e.g.

```
SELECT postId, postContent, postDate, 'post' AS type FROM posts
UNION ALL
SELECT commentId, commentContent, commentDate, 'comment' FROM comments
```

Then, when you iterate your result set in PHP, you may access the `type` key/column to figure out whether that record be a post or a comment.

Comment: i get the type and comment keywords how do i work with them?

Comment: @DuduClau _You_ are sort of supposed to tell _us_ this.  I mean, I don't know what you want to do with your data, and maybe a union query does not even make good sense.  My answer offers a way out of the exact problem you reported to us.

Comment: i can't get the comments in php saying undefined variable

Comment: i need to get the comments as well and work with them

Comment: And I gave you a way to do this.  You simply check `row['type']` and when that equals `comment`, then you know that record is a comment, and not a post.

Comment: it works verry well thanks a lot how do i order them now?

Comment: how do i add a where clause here?

Comment: any help please?